# Android Gridview Making Images Larger

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin, tableview

Am trying to use Android GridView to show 2 columns of images.

```
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Am running the app on a Samsung J2 physical device. The screenshot looks like this

[image: App Screenshot]

**Help!**

1. I can't get the images to be any bigger - they are all 200x150 - the screenshot does not look anywhere near displaying 200x150. I have tried every option - but the correct one.
2. I want to display a text under each image - GridView does not seem to have an option. Will I have to use the TableView?

Many thanks

Iyer

Comment: You can use custom GridView Adapter to make the text under each image

Comment: use custom GridView Adapter or recycle view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes my friend you can use custom layout and an adapter that extends `BaseAdapter` to achieve your need. follow the below steps.

==> cust_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cga_iv"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/Al_grid_image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/Al_grid_image_height" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/cga_txt_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

==> cust_adpt.java

Custom class that extends `BaseAdapter` and implement its all overriden methods

```
public class cust_adpt extends BaseAdapter {
```

Make changes in `getview` method like following.here AlCover and AlBuckName are my arrayLists that containing my data and sets in gridview for `ImageView` and `TextView` respectively.

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View v, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_grid_album, null, true);

    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.cga_iv);

    TextView txtname = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cga_txt_name);


    //setting image
    Glide.with(context).load(AlCover.get(i)).placeholder(android.R.color.white).centerCrop().into(iv);


    //setting text
    txtname.setText(AlBuckName.get(i));


    return view;

}
```

And finally you can simply set adapter in your activity.here imagedata and textdata are arraylists that contains images and texts respectively.

```
gridView.setAdapter(new cust_adpt((Activity) context, imagedata, textdata));
```

Do let me know if you still face any problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this like](https://www.learn2crack.com/2016/03/grid-recyclerview-with-images-and-text.html) out! I think this very nice starting example for you to do what you want.

Hope this will help you.